# Docker not copying files specified in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile, windows-server-2019

I'm currently running a Windows Server 2019 host, and I'm trying to get Visual Studio Build Tools and SSDT installed on a `windowsservercore:lts2019` image. I am able to do successful quiet installs of both if I mount the directory when I run the container with `docker run -it -v <src>:<dst> image:tag powershell` and run the .exes with `quiet` flags, however I need the installed files to be available within the container so I am trying to do this install within the Dockerfile. Here's what I have:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
SHELL ["powershell.exe", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "-Command"]
RUN (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).Downloadfile('http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=210285', 'C:\\jre-8u91-windows-x64.exe')
RUN Start-Process -filepath 'C:\\jre-8u91-windows-x64.exe' -passthru -wait -argumentlist "/s,INSTALLDIR=$env:JAVA_HOME,/L,install64.log"
RUN del 'C:\\jre-8u91-windows-x64.exe'
RUN $env:PATH = $env.JAVA_HOME + '\\bin;' + $env:PATH; \
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $env:PATH, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine);
COPY ./vs_setup.exe .
COPY ./SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe .
RUN vs_setup.exe -q --norestart --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Professional
RUN SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe /install installvssql:ssdt /quiet /wait /norestart
RUN SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe /install INSTALLALL /quiet /wait /norestart
CMD ["powershell.exe", "-nologo"]
```

That reports that the COPY commands ran successfully, however once the step to run the .exes that I'd tried copying over is run, I get the error that 'vs_setup.exe' is not a recognized cmdlet, function, etc.

I do a `docker run -it image:tag powershell`, I can see that `C:\installs` exists but it's empty. The .exes that I'm trying to copy are in the same directory level as the Dockerfile being ran. Is there anyway to get these copied and installed in the Dockerfile?

---

#### Edit:

I've updated the Dockerfile to show that the Java stuff isn't changing directories, or at least *shouldn't* be. The folder structure is:

```
        Directory: C:\projects

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         6/25/2019  3:13 PM           4291 Dockerfile
-a----         6/27/2019 10:54 AM        1608400 SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe
-a----         5/16/2019  3:20 PM        1286728 vs_setup.exe
```

As much as I would like this to work I think that I'll need to mount a volume and install these manually, then use multi-stage builds and `docker commit` to create a new image off of the post-install container. I'll keep this updated with what works.

Comment: you are coping from installs subfolder into image root. Yet you say that exes are next to docker file this does not make sense. You say installs folder is empty do you expect your exes in installs folder on your image? its unclear can you draw you folder structure, and list files in rood of your result image. And are you sure that java stuff is not changing current folder.

Comment: I can add more details, I might not be able to until tomorrow morning but I'll get them added once I'm able.

Comment: Added updates @Rafal

Comment: I would use fully qualified paths, or make WORKDIR explicit, or have RUN commands printing more stuff